# htaccess redirect conflict/not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a QR code that I need to redirect to a new page. For some reason the redirect is being overridden (ends up at cmdgroup.com/community instead of the appropritate page)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?companies/Inova-Solutions-Inc/Network-Clocks-by-Inova-Solutions/53e4f5e048e43c1d5cef656d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cmdgroup.com/companies/1142841/inova-solutions-inc/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?community.cmdgroup.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?community.reedconstructiondata.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cmdgroup.com/community/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your first `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` is wrong since you only match domain name using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. Change that rule to this:

```
RewriteRule companies/Inova-Solutions-Inc/Network-Clocks-by-Inova-Solutions/53e4f5e048e43c1d5cef656d$ http://www.cmdgroup.com/companies/1142841/inova-solutions-inc/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} community\.(cmdgroup|reedconstructiondata)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.cmdgroup.com/community/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either. I replaced my code with the snippet you sent, but I still get the same result. This link: community.reedconstructiondata.com/companies/Inova-Solutions-Inc/Network-Clocks-by-Inova-Solutions/53e4f5e048e43c1d5cef656d 
ends up at: http://www.cmdgroup.com/community

Comment: What URL didn't work? Make sure you test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: OK it was the cache. Thank you sir!